# AWK - minimum value each item

Tags: awk

I have the file data.txt with the following:

```
Claude:41:166:Paris
John:37:185:Miami
Lina:16:170:Miami
Maurice:58:172:Paris
Phoebe:21:179:Paris
Anthony:69:165:Brasilia
```

Being the number after the first colon the age of each one I tried to the get the name of the youngest person of every city by:

```
sort -t ":" -k4,1 -k2,2 datos.txt |  awk -F ':' '!a[$4]++' | sort -t ":" -k4
```

My question is: is there a more efficient way? Can I just have the name of the person and the city? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it entirely in `awk`. Use an array to hold the youngest age for each city, and a second array to hold the name of the person with that age.

```
awk -F: '!age[$4] || $2 < age[$4] { age[$4] = $2; name[$4] = $1; }
         END {for (city in name) print city, name[city] }' datos.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get the name of the person, you can split on `':'` and just print part 1 and 4, like this `| awk -F: '{print $1 " " $4}'`

Giving:

```
sort -t ":" -k4,1 -k2,2 datos.txt |  awk -F ':' '!a[$4]++' | sort -t ":" -k4 | awk -F: '{print $1 " " $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

without `awk`

```
$ sort -t: -k4,4 -k2,2 file |  # sort by city, age
  tr ':' ' '                |  # replace delimiter
  uniq -f3                  |  # take the min for each city
  tr ' ' ':'                   # replace delimiter back

Anthony:69:165:Brasilia
Lina:16:170:Miami
Phoebe:21:179:Paris
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print only required field within `awk`, further sorting is not needed as the first `sort` already specifies the order

```
$ # printing required field with space between (default OFS)
$ sort -t: -k4,4 -k2,2 ip.txt | awk -F: '!a[$4]++{print $1, $4}'
Anthony Brasilia
Lina Miami
Phoebe Paris

$ # printing with : between fields
$ sort -t: -k4,4 -k2,2 ip.txt | awk -F: '!a[$4]++{print $1 ":" $4}'
Anthony:Brasilia
Lina:Miami
Phoebe:Paris
```

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ datamash -t: -s -g4 min 2 < ip.txt 
Brasilia:69
Miami:16
Paris:21
```

however, as far as I've understood from manual, it doesn't allow to print only specific fields